# Zend_Translate and translation issues

Tags: zend-framework, zend-translate

I wonder how I could translate the following?

```
(french) Vous avez oublié votre <a href="/auth/password-recovery">mot de passe</a> ?
(english) Forgot your <a href="/auth/password-recovery">password</a> ?
(dutch) <a href="/auth/password-recovery">Paswoord</a> vergeten ?
```

As you may notice, the problem is that in the dutch version, the sentence starts with password and in the french and english version, it starts with the subject/verb.

I usually do it like this:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('Vous avez oublié votre'); ?>
<a href="/auth/password-recovery"><?php echo $this->translate('mot de passe'); ?></a> ?
```

Unfortunately that won't work here because as said earlier in the dutch version the sentence starts with the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use embedded parameters ( %1\$s): http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.using.html